# Does Ada have any idiomatic rules on when to use a function versus a procedure with an output parameter?

Tags: ada

You can assign to a variable by having a function return a value to it:

`My_Int : Integer := My_Math_Func [(optional params)];`

Or you can do it like this with a procedure (assuming `My_Int` has already been declared):

`My_Math_Proc ([optional params;] [in] out My_Int);`

Obviously a procedure can't initialize a variable like the function does in the first example, but I'm hoping for some concrete, practical rules on when and why to pick one over the other.

Comment: Side note:  You can actually turn an initializing procedure into a function if you need using Ada2012's extended return syntax.  See this example:  https://ideone.com/VXOylN

Comment: @Jere That would make a useful answer, I think.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Ok, I'll add it.  Thanks! I wasn't sure if it was appropriate since it is more "extra info"

Comment: @Jere Extended return is Ada 2005.

Comment: @darkestkhan Yep.  SO doesn't allow me to edit comments, so I couldn't go back and change that.  I did make sure to use the correct version in my answer later on.  It is at least worth noting that they updated the feature in Ada2012 to be more useful, especially with constants and class wide types.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two to get you started...

When more than one result is to be returned, a procedure with several OUT parameters is often a good choice.

When the size of the object is unknown prior to the subprogram call, an OUT parameter cannot be used because it would have to be declared precisely the right size, but a function return can set the size by initialising the variable in the caller. This is commonly used with a variable declared in a Declare block, which can hold a different sized string each time it is invoked.

This example shows the variable "text" initialised by calling a `Read_File` function, to hold the contents of a different file on each iteration of the loop. Safe, no "malloc" or "free" or pointers necessary. (`Filename` is an array of filenames in this example)

```
for i in 1 .. last_file loop
   declare
      text : String := Read_File(Filename(i));
      -- the size of "text" is determined by the file contents
   begin
      --   process the text here. 
      for j in text'range loop
         if text(j) = '*' then 
         ...
      end loop;
   end
end loop;
```

Edit : And I suppose I'd better mention the underlying mathematical principle, since Ada is based more closely on mathematical logic than many other languages.

Functions and procedures are both subprograms, but for different purposes:

- a function is an abstraction over an expression : like a mathematical operator (and an operator in Ada is just a function). Ideally, it provides a result from a number of operands **and nothing else**, leaving them unchanged and having no state and no side effects. This ideal is called a "pure function" (and applying "pragma pure" asks the compiler to check its purity) - similar restrictions apply in functional programming (FP) languages. Pure functions allow a whole bunch of optimisation (because reordering them doesn't change results). In practice Ada is not that strict, allowing impure functions too.
- a procedure is an abstraction over a statement. It generally has some physical effect (such as changing state) since it doesn't deliver a result.

So the logical separation between expressions and statements is carried over into subprograms (abstractions) as the separation between functions and procedures.

And this is probably the best way to decide which to use.

Comment: So in your example, if `Read_File` were a procedure with an `out` parameter, then `text` would have to be declared as the exact right length of the file being read? That does indeed sound impractical.

Comment: Alternatively, make the procedure return an access type (pointer) and remember to free it when done. Feasible, but that's just using Ada to write a C program.

Comment: That sounds even worse! ;)

Answer (score 6):

Brian Drummond already answered your question directly, but I wanted to add some additional info:  If your type has some sort of initializing procedure, in Ada2005/Ada2012 you can convert it to an initializing function using [extended return syntax](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-6-5.html#I3515).  It will even work for limited types.

Say you have a package with a type like this:

```ada
package Example is

    type My_Type is limited private;

    procedure Initialize(Self : in out My_Type; Value : Integer);
    procedure Print(Self : My_Type);

private

    type My_Type is limited record
        Value : Integer := 0;
    end record;

end Example;

package body Example is
    procedure Initialize(Self : in out My_Type; Value : Integer) is
    begin
        Self.Value := Value;
    end Initialize;

    procedure Print(Self : My_Type) is
    begin
        Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line(Self.Value'Image);
    end Print;
end Example;
```

You can then make your own initializing function out of that procedure doing something like this:

```ada
function Make_My_Type (Value : Integer) return Example.My_Type is
begin
    return Result : Example.My_Type do
        Example.Initialize(Result,Value);
    end return;
end Make_My_Type;
```

and you can initialize variables easily using the procedure hidden in your function underneath:

```ada
procedure Test
   Thing : Example.My_Type := Make_My_Type(21);
begin
   Example.Print(Thing);
end Test;
```

This is different than just making a variable and returning it.  You are not able to do that with a limited type, but with [extended return syntax](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-6-5.html#I3515), you can do it for any type.

Here is [some additional info for extended return statements](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rat/html/Rat12-4-6.html) as well.

Comment: "limited type" means a type which cannot be assigned. One common use is for the "singleton" design pattern.

Comment: I think this is a great answer: it explains a language-specific feature relevant to the question, and a language-specific situation where you might see it. This answer and the second point in Brian 's answer were exactly the type of thing I was hoping for.